# How to decompress a PVRTC compressed image format to view it on a PC

Tags: image, compression, pvrtc

I need a texture out of an iphone game whitch is compressed in a PVRTC image format.
I´ve tried the PVRTexTool to decompress it but the image doesnt open in it. The program only opens files with the file extension .PVR...
I found a code that apparently decompresses it.´(link below)
The problem is it opens with Microsoft Visual C++ (Express) and I have no idea how that program works
Weirdly enough the debug button is always grayed out.
PLS can someone help? I have no idea how Visual C++ works...

https://bitbucket.org/stopiccot/lobster/src/b1c7b9e19424/code/windows/pvrtc/PVRTDecompress.cpp

Answer (score 1):

That is fairly generic C/C++ code that appears to have been lifted from the [Imagination Technologies developer pages](http://www.imgtec.com/developers.asp). You should be able to compile and link it in to your own C/C++ program using whatever development environment you like.  You *don't* have to use MS Visual studio....

... or are you saying you don't understand the C language? If the latter, then you probably on the wrong forum.